# System statistics in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

Is there an easy way in Ubuntu to show the specifications of the computer, such as RAM, the kind of processor, graphics card, etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Various virtual files in the `/proc` filesystem contain a fair bit of info in human readable format, for instance:
`cat /proc/cpuinfo` for cpu details
`cat /proc/meminfo` for amount of RAM and what the kernel is doing with it (though `free -m` does the same thing if you don't need as much detail)

Also other things like:

`sudo dmidecode | less` for a chunk of fairly detailed hardware info
`sudo lshw | less` similar but with more formatting options (see `man lshw` for more hints)

There are several GUI utilities available too. `sysinfo` for instance, which is not installed by default but is in the standard repositories so install with `sudo aptitude install sysinfo` (or find it in the GUI package manager) and then run `sysinfo` to call it into action. There is also a graphical interface for `lshw` which shows much more detail but in a slightly less accessible way - run `sudo aptitude install lshw-gtk` (or use the GUI package manager) to install and `sudo lshw-gtk` to run.

Answer (score 0):

sure just look under /proc/ in the filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I've found (rather than `less /proc/cpuinfo` etc.) is to open a terminal, type `sudo lshw -html > hardwareprofile.html`, enter your password at the prompt and wait for the command to finish. Then go to your home folder (places menu -> home) and double-click `hardwareprofile.html`; it should open in Firefox (or whatever browser you are using) and you'll be able to see the full specifications of your system. Cheers!